# Returning a file with status code 201 in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

After a successful resource creation, I would like to return a PDF representation of the resource along with the status code `201 Created`.

My byte array with the file I want to return is called `document`.

### CreatedResult

First I tried to use `CreatedResult` class `Created("https://...", document)`. It returns the `201 Created` status, but the document is returned as a base64 string and the content type is set to "application/json".

### FileContentResult

Then I tried returning a `FileContentResult(document, "application/pdf")`. This time, the document is returned as a file, which is OK, but the status code is `200 OK` (and I see no way to change it to a `201 Created`).

**Is there a way in ASP.NET Core 2 I can return a file, along with a specific content-type and a status code of 201 Created?** Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried a solution but encountered a strange behavior.  It could work depending of your need.  Just write "Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;" before returning your result.  Using safari, I can open the PDF but under chrome, it doesn't like the answer (not opening the file although it received the information and the right status code)

Comment: I'm not sure why would you return a file that was just uploaded but have you looked into overriding the `FileContentResult()` method or creating your own method e.g. `FileContentCreatedResult()`?

Comment: @hugo thank you. This worked. Please can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, use the syntax

```
FileContentResult(document, "application/pdf")
```

but write the following code before returning your result

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
```